# JavaFx : Disable Divider

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, divider, splitpane

I have a **JavaFX** application with a **SplitPane**. I want to disable the **Divider** on **SplitPane**, so it would not be possible to change its position when application is running. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no API for that, so once the scene is shown we have to use a lookup function to find the node by its id. In this case, the `Divider` has this id: `split-pane-divider`.

Once we find the node, we set it transparent to mouse events:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
    splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    splitPane.setDividerPositions(new double[]{0.5});
    splitPane.getItems().add(new StackPane(new Label("Left")));
    splitPane.getItems().add(new StackPane(new Label("Right")));

    Scene scene = new Scene(splitPane, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    splitPane.lookupAll(".split-pane-divider").stream()
            .forEach(div ->  div.setMouseTransparent(true) );

}
```

Comment: This is great, but for applications with more than one split pane, all will be disabled.  How to set the id of a split panes divider?

Comment: You can use the `lookup` only with the intended splitPane that contains the divider you want to disable.

Comment: Does this still work with JavaFX 8? I can't get it to work. No node is found with lookup.

Comment: It still works, indeed. You can use ScenicView to find the divider, and see that it still uses the same style class. Also make sure to call lookup _after_ the stage is shown.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I added a listener to the divider and rewrote the slider position when it was changed. Its hacky but only a few lines of code and worked.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above posts worked for me. I have found this solution which worked for me:
This code works for the case when your splitPane is divided in the middle and has only one divider, therefore the divider's position is set to `0.5`. If you don't know the position of the divider, you can get it by `divider.getPosition();`.

```
        Divider divider = splitPane.getDividers().get(0);
    divider.positionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()      
    {             
        @Override 
        public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldvalue, Number newvalue )
        {
            divider.setPosition(0.5);
        }
    });
```

This code is in the `initialize()` method of the GUI Controller class.

Comment: This solution works perfectly when you still need the mouse NOT to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Set mouseTransparent="true" of SplitPane in Fxml file.

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="652.0" prefWidth="858.0">
```

Comment: This results in all containing nodes in the splitpane also beeing mouseTransparent. Thisway you can't interact with any child via mouse anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the Skin class for SplitPane. Just copy the code from GrepCode for SplitPaneSkin (available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/SplitPaneSkin.java)) and remove the MouseListeners in method initializeDivderEventHandlers() and also the setCursor calls in method setGrabberStyle() and then you can't resize the pane by dragging the divider ;-) At the end you only have to set the skin to the SplitPane by calling setSkin.